# des-habilitar una imagen con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo una duda, tengo una imagen que al presionarla me ejecuta una función. Quisiera saber como puedo des-habilitar la imagen y/o la función una vez que esta ya ha sido ejecutada.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola!, por deshabilitar la imagen, ¿a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: a que ya no realice más la función

Comment: Que has intentado?, Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta por favor edita y agrega que llevas

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hola si le puedes agregar esta clase de css.

Documentación sobre pointer-events: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```js
$("img").on('click', function(){
  alert("hola")
})
```

```css
 .not-active { 
                pointer-events: none; 
                cursor: default; 
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <img width='300' class='not-active'  src='https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20190820147813/razas-perros-pequenos-parecen-grandes/0-711-550/razas-perro-pequenos-grandes-m.jpg'>

<img width='300'  src='https://www.hola.com/imagenes/estar-bien/20190820147813/razas-perros-pequenos-parecen-grandes/0-711-550/razas-perro-pequenos-grandes-m.jpg'>
```

Comment: Hola, veo que respondes continuamente a preguntas que no estan realizadas en base a [ask], te sugiero ayudes a los usuarios a mejorar sus preguntas, para que sean de ayuda a toda la comunidad no únicamente al que pregunta, de otra forma estas contribuyendo a la baja de calidad en la información del sitio.

Comment: muchas gracias, la primera parte donde iría, js, html o css?

Comment: aqui puedes ver donde va https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp